# Error while validating constraint x_ creating a model in struture database

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am creating a new database model, but when saving information throws me an error `Error while validating constraint`

[image]

[image]

Be a permission error user database? Will be a topic of privileges ??

Answer (score 0):

I cant translate your picture what are you doing there but maybe module named x_hola is already is there and you are making another one so constraint tells you that you are using same name what is forbidden by this constraint. 
Hope I helped you a little